# GridControl set layoutview's value text

Tags: c#, winforms, devexpress, datagridviewcolumn, gridcontrol

I have a GridControl (devexpress) with 10 columns.
I want to set the columns text and the field's text as well.
To set the column's text i simply do `layoutViewField_layoutViewColumn1.Text = "test";`
However i can't find out how can i set the value of the field next to the column's text.
I don't actually know how those controls are called so i will upload a picture to show you what i mean.[image]

So it is the value of the text next to the layoutview text.
I hope it is clear enough...

Comment: Did you specify FieldNames for your columns?

Comment: Yes. layoutViewField_layoutViewColumn1 is what you mean i gues?